# Scheme using modulo operator on a list

Tags: list, scheme, modulo

i found the max value of a list and now i want to return the numbers except all the numbers that have a modulo equal to zero with the MAX value and im not quite sure how to use the modulo operator on the whole list to get the numbers i need can anyone lead me in the right direction this is what i have so far

```
(define (findlargest a_list)
(if (null? a_list) ;if its a empty list
    #f             ;its false
    (let loop ((a_list (cdr a_list)) ;binds the loop variable a_list to value of cdr a_list(second and all subsequent items in a list)
               (maxval (car a_list))) ;maxval is set to car of a_list (first item of the list)
      (cond ((null? a_list) maxval)   ;if the list is empty return max
            ((> (car a_list) maxval)  ;checks to see if the current element > max
             (loop (cdr a_list) (car a_list))) ;find a new max
            (else
        (loop (cdr a_list) maxval)));keeps the same max
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reinventing the wheel with `findlargest`, there's a [built-in procedure](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._max%29%29) for that:

```
(define (findlargest lst)
  (apply max lst))
```

Now, regarding your question - this looks like a perfect job for [`filter`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29):

```
(define (filter-max-modulo lst)
  (let ((max-val (findlargest lst)))
    (filter (lambda (val)
              (not (zero? (modulo val max-val))))
            lst)))
```

For example:

```
(filter-max-modulo '(0 -2 -4 -3 -7 -1 2))
=> '(-3 -7 -1)
```